# Setting the AudioContext input

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I am using the [SpeechRecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) API in a web page. I'd like to show a visualization as the user speaks. For example, I'd like to be able to show some bars like [these](https://github.com/wayou/audio-visualizer-with-controls). When I look at the code shown in that example, it seems that I need to use the [AudioContext API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext). My challenge is I do not see how to link the SpeechRecognition API to the AudioContext API. Is there a way to do this?

I know that it's experimental tech. I just kind of assumed I could use the microphone as an input for audio context.

Answer (score 1):

get the mic with getUserMedia and Route the Buffer to your Analyzer Script.

There is no connection between the two API's so you need to do that seperately.